Pannellum how to show info texts without having to hover the mouse
I want to be able to modify the texts of an info hotspot in Pannellum's library. I tried to set the default property in false, or show instead of hidden and even tried the visibility class in CSS but id didn't work. I've been investigating about another library but i coudln't find.

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...
